# How to overlay two images in ios6 with transparency

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to overlay two images and put text on top in a view that I have.  I have this working perfectly in ios7. Here is a screen shot of the results

[image: Desired Results]

Right now the gradient is simply an image on top of the other image as seen here in my layout

[image: Layout]

This works great except for when I test on my phone with ios6. Then everything goes nuts as seen here. *I've actually deleted the gradient layer and ran the app again and the background image remains the same size (about half of what it should be).

[image: Images messed up in ios6]

As you can see, the background image is only half of what it should be, and the second image is not overlaying. I've been at this for 5 hours and can't seem to find a solution that works.

Here is the code that sets the background image

```
-(void) SetDetails
{
if(_curInfo)
{


    _lblTopName.text = _curInfo.company_name;
    if(!_curInfo.img)
    {
        showActivity(self);
        dispatch_queue_t aQueue1 = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_async(aQueue1, ^{
            _curInfo.img = getImageFromURL([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", g_serverUrl, _curInfo.imgPath]);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                hideActivity();
                [_imgCompany setImage:_curInfo.img];
            });
        });
    }
    [_imgCompany setImage:_curInfo.img];



    /* FIX IMAGE SIZE */
    _imgCompany.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    CGRect photoFrame = _imgCompany.frame;
    photoFrame.size = CGSizeMake(320, 180);
    _imgCompany.frame=photoFrame;
    [_imgCompany setClipsToBounds:YES];


        _lblDistance.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f miles", _curInfo.distance];


    _lblReward.text=_curInfo.reward;

    CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 0.0f;
    for (UIView* view in scroller.subviews)
    {
        scrollViewHeight += view.frame.size.height;

    }

    [scroller setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(320, scrollViewHeight))];

}
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm not opposed to drawing the gradient onto the image either.

Additional Info:

Here is how I have the two image views setup.

[image: Gradient Image View]

[image: Background Image View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unstick the 'opaque' option on your image view, given that it isn't opaque.

As to the other spacing issue, I'd guess it's a mismatch between iOS 7 view controllers always acting as if they had `wantsFullScreenLayout` set to `YES` but the default having been `NO` under iOS 6. The rest of your image is probably underneath your navigation bar. It looks like you're part trying the interface builder and part doing programmatic layout — why did you add the code underneath `FIX IMAGE SIZE` and what happens if you remove it?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. I unselected the opaque option and received the same results. If I take the code out under `FIX IMAGE SIZE` the images don't resize to the size that I have set in the interface builder. Instead some will be taller than others and cover up the text below.  I want the image to always be the same size 320 x 180, and the image resize to fit that space.

Comment: Taking the issues separately — just setting clips to bounds to `YES` and scale to fill should eliminate the need to fix image size if you also disable the relevant autosizing. You probably want all horizontal bars enabled but only the top red beam vertically. Does that at least resolve that aspect of the problem?

Comment: It's getting closer, I think I may be missing something fundamental here. In the interface builder I have the image set to 320 x 180. Removing the bottom red beam makes all the images the same size (win), however they are at 320x240 for some reason. I do not have autolayout enabled because this project was built in an earlier version of xCode and turning it on causes a lot of problems on all of my screens.

Comment: Do you have the two-headed vertical arrow enabled? If the struts outside are enabled then the edges of the view will try to remain that distance from the edges of the screen. If the arrow (which used to be a spring) is enabled then the view will try to scale proportionally with the parent.

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking everyone to try and figure out how that layout box worked. That fixed all of my problems.